# Dynamically Changing Table Names

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I am currently working with a database that has read and write tables.

There are always two tables with the same schema, distinguished by a number as suffix, eg. table1 and table2.

Now, there is another source where I get the current number from. I have to use this number to select from the corresponding table with the matching suffix.

Right now, for every table i have a @MappedSuperclass containing the schema and two implementation classes specifying the table name via @Table(name = "..1") and @Table(name = "..2").

This solution works but by now I discovered a lot of drawbacks and fear there will be many more. Is there another, better way to solve this?

Unfortunately, I could not find out what this kind of database mechanism is called hence I could not find any other sources on the internet.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this a legacy system or something? The use of table naming like this doesn't make much sense, which is probably why you can't find a lot of info on it.  Any chance you can redesign to not use two different tables?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have to use the database as designed..

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution:

```
    if ( num == 1 )
    {
      Table1 table1 = createTable1();
      table1.set...;
      entityManager.persist( table1 );
    } else
    {
      Table2 table2 = createTable2();
      table2.set...;
      entityManager.persist( table2 );
    }
```

Or with constructor calling by name (with Lombok annotations):

```
@Entity
@Data
public class CommonBase
{}

@Entity
@Data
public class Table1 extends CommonBase
{}

@Entity
@Data
public class Table2 extends CommonBase
{}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class CommonBaseBean
{
  @Inject
  private CommonBaseBUS commonBaseBUS;

  protected void clientCode()
  {
    Table0 t0 = (Table0) commonBaseBUS.createEntityByIndex( 0 );
    t0.set...();
    commonBaseBUS.persisEntity( t0 );

    Table1 t1 = (Table1) commonBaseBUS.createEntityByIndex( 1 );
    t1.set...();
    commonBaseBUS.persisEntity( t1 );
  }
}

@Dependent
class CommonBaseBUS
{
  @Inject
  private CommonBaseDAL commonBaseDAL;

  @Setter
  private String entityBaseName = "qualified.path.Table";

  public CommonBase createEntityByIndex( int index_ ) throws ClassNotFoundException
  {
    String entityName = entityBaseName + Integer.toString( index_ );
    return createEntityByName( entityName );
  }

  public void persisEntity( CommonBase cb_ )
  {
    commonBaseDAL.persistEntity( cb_ );
  }

  protected CommonBase createEntityByName( String entityName_ ) throws ClassNotFoundException
  {
    Class<?> c = Class.forName( entityName_ );
    try
    {
      return (CommonBase) c.newInstance();
    }
    catch ( InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex )
    {
      throw new ClassNotFoundException();
    }
  }
}

@Dependent
class CommonBaseDAL
{
  @PersistentContext
  private EntityManager em;

  public void persisEntity( CommonBase cb_ )
  {
    em.persistEntity( cb_ );
  }        
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This is the obvious solution i wanted to avoid. I ended up using superclasses. The only thing that needs the actual implementation is the jpa entitymanager for which i am resolving the classes via hard-coded enums

Comment: You can use a superclass for them, but i do not know : is there any common attributes? If not it is a bad idea. Wrong design decision.

Comment: @Benjamin W: I would not be honest if I told you I fully understand what is the point of this question. But I don't want to downrate it.